# Integrating the derivative of the derivative squared

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am trying to understand a calculation made in a text book.

We have the following equation:

$A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\mathrm{sin(y)}$

Then is it stated that multiplying both side with dy/dx and then integrating we must get:

$A \frac{1}{2} \big( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \big)^2=\mathrm{cos(y)}+C$.

I do not  understand the calculation. Multiplying both sides with dy/dx , we get:

$A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\mathrm{sin(y)}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$

Integrating with respect to dx on both sides we get:

$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int \mathrm{sin(y)}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$

which then can be written as

$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int \mathrm{sin(y)}\mathrm{d}y$

Yielding:

$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=cos(y)+C$.

I understand how he get the right hand side, but not the left hand side.

My guess is that maybe he is rewriting the left hand side as:

$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$=$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d}  }{\mathrm{d}x} 
\big( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \big) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$=$\int$ $A\frac{\mathrm{d}  }{\mathrm{d}x} 
\big( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \big)^2\mathrm{d}x$

I am not sure...

Comment: Note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 \right) = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You should write $-\cos (y) $.